# Subview button is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolevents

```
masterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.masterBed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

i have used above code in subview but it doesn't fire function `masterBed`.
the button within subview is not clickable

Full code:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
button.center = CGPoint(x: 380, y: 110)
button.setTitle(">", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
self.addSubview(button)

func buttonAction () {
    print("button pressed")
}
```

Comment: Did you set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` for the button or did you enable it in Storyboard?

Comment: Can you provide more details? As is your question is not very useful.

Comment: i have write this code in subview and call buttonAction function but nothing print in console. and actually i am not using storyboard.
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        button.center = CGPoint(x: 380, y: 110)
        button.setTitle(">", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)

Comment: func buttonAction () {
       print("button pressed")
    }

Comment: @RushikeshWelkar in the future please edit your original question with properly formatted code, instead of posting it as a comment. I have included your comment in the question for now. And you should try enabling user interaction as I explained in my first comment.

Comment: ok ..thanks@DávidPásztor

Comment: you have defined buttonAction instead of masterBed method on button click, so it'll not invoke the masterBed method.

Comment: both are used for different buttons please consider buttonAction code @RahulKumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the height and width of the subview remains 0 because the button is not bound to any edges and the button seem to define the height of its superview. You could always check this by settings clipToBounds = true. Its always good to call the lazy if you are using self within an view.

This should solve your problem:

```
class buttonView: UIView {
private lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("MyButton", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    addSubview(button)
    
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 35))
}

@objc func buttonAction() {
    //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Slightly unsure about the NSLayoutConstraints, since i use SnapKit or anchorpoints. But i think this should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem. To solve it just set isUserInteractionEnabled = true to PARENT view (view were you add button subview)

Answer (score 1):

inside on the Masterbed property, put userinteractionenbaled = true, that will fix the problem, other stuff is the addSubview... put that on the subView Item or Class.. like masterBed.addSubView(youurButton) and if you use userinteration on the button.. really has no sense because the button is already an object created for interacions.. it's the same thing if we put a button on UIImageView, we need activated on the property on the UIImageView, to interact with the button. like this Sample..

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

 let myImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true    // here activate the interaction needed
    image.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "backgroundSE.jpg")
    return image
}()

let textLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "My App"
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

lazy var sendMailButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Send Mail", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSendMail), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    view.addSubview(myImage)
    myImage.addSubview(sendMailButton)
    myImage.addSubview(textLabel)

    setupLayouts()

}

@objc func handleSendMail() {
    print("Mail Sended")
}
```

I hope this help you and fix the problem, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code as below, it's working.

**Your ViewController Class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, HomeViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        middleView()
    }

    func middleView() {
        let customView = HomeView(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 250, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(customView)
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        customView.delegate = self
    }

    func buttonAclicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button click action in viewController")
    }

}
```

**HomeView Class**

```
import UIKit

protocol HomeViewDelegate {

    func buttonAclicked(_ sender: UIButton)
}

class HomeView: UIView {

    var delegate:HomeViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func initView() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 80, height: 35))
        self.addSubview(button)
        button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("MyButton", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button pressed")
        delegate?.buttonAclicked(sender)
    }

}
```

Comment: But i want code related to UIView not to view controller @RahulKumar

Comment: I didn't get, are you using extension for UIView?

Comment: I have create class  for UIView i.e-   class homeView:UIView {  }

Comment: Can you share the relevant code inside that class, and viewController code where you are creating the instance of homeView?

Comment: @RushikeshWelkar, I have updated the code, It's working check once.

Comment: let's see i have use one view controller and one view i.e. homeView when execute the button in subview is not clickable also i have used protocol for subview i.e. for homeView. i am new in swift so i didn't get how to use button for subview.

Comment: Make sure your button's frame comes inside HomeView's frame. May be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: just add the _ sender: UIButton to your buttenPressed Func and than its working

Comment: if not, than bring it to front, self.bringSubviewToFront(button) or so

Comment: @RahulKumar can i contact with for detail information about my topic.

Comment: Yes, sure. let me know about it.

Comment: plz give me your whats up ya mobile no..@RahulKumar

Comment: @RushikeshWelkar, Can you share the details at my email rahuldbs@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0):

might be your subview is out off parent view frame so can you try to give same frame as parent view frame and try like this:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: self.frame)//Parent view frame
button.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
//button.center = CGPoint(x: 380, y: 110) // comment this line 
button.setTitle(">", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
self.addSubview(button)
```